# Regular Expression Tester for Google RE2

Tags: regex, re2

I'm looking for a regular expression tester for Google Big Data (RE2) reg expressions. There are a few testers out there, but none of them seems to understand my statement. These are the ones I've tried and they've worked for simple expressions but not with mine:

- https://regex101.com/
- https://www.regextester.com
- https://www.analyticsmarket.com/freetools/regex-tester/

This is my regex:

`^(?:1-)?((?:R|RO|Ro)?[:|.]?\\s?\\d{3}[-|.]?\\d{4}[-|/]F\\d{2}-\\d{2})$`

where I would process strings like these:

- Ro 708-2859/F07-01
- RO708-2859-F06-04
- RO703-3877-F01
- 1-RO520-0628-F08
- RO6868847-000-010

Does anyone have an idea of how I might enter the statement different or where I could test it?

Comment: Hi, as I mentioned I would process all examples with this regex.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use

```golang
^(?:1-)?((?:R[Oo]?)?[:.]?\s?\d{3}[-.]?\d{4}[-/](?:F\d{2}(?:-\d{2})?|\d{3}[-/]\d{3}))$
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/BgMkwf/2). *Details*:

- `^` - start of string
- `(?:1-)?` - an optional `1-` string
- `((?:R[Oo]?)?[:.]?\s?\d{3}[-.]?\d{4}[-/](?:F\d{2}(?:-\d{2})?|\d{3}[-/]\d{3}))` - Group 1:

  - `(?:R[Oo]?)?` - an optional sequence of `R` and then an optional `O` or `o`
  - `[:.]?` - an optional `:` or `.`
  - `\s?` - an optional whitespace
  - `\d{3}` - three digits
  - `[-.]?` - an optional `-` or `.`
  - `\d{4}` - four digits
  - `[-/]` - `-` or `/`
  - `(?:F\d{2}(?:-\d{2})?|\d{3}[-/]\d{3})` - either `F`, two digits and then an optional sequence of `-` and two digits, or three digits, `-` or `/` and three digits
- `$` - end of string.

See the Google Sheets demo:

[image]

Answer (score 2):

You may try to use https://www.regexplanet.com/advanced/golang/index.html

I've tried your regexp, and this also pointing to Re2 for docs.